# Wrap text in td without breaking the word

Tags: javascript, html, css, word-wrap

I have an issue in word wrapping in CSS. I have a `td` where I have defined `width` as `300px`. I have a url inside the td like

```
http://www.abc.com/testing/testdata/testurl/test/testing.html
```

When I use `word-wrap: break-word`, the text is wrapping as

```
http://www.abc.com/testing/testdata/tes
turl/test/testing.html
```

But I do want the word to break. Like `/tes` in one line and `turl` in another line. I want it as,

```
 http://www.abc.com/testing/testdata/testurl/
 test/testing.html
```

Kindly help. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**Updated**:

I also have probability of getting text other than URL. Means I can't relay on `'/'` in the data. I can use javascript not jquery.

Comment: This is not related with Html or CSS :) You will probably need a server side language for it, like PHP.

Comment: Can't we control this in CSS. I think we can.. Kindly correct me if am wrong..

Comment: CSS won't recognise `/` as distinct from the other characters, so it won't break it there. It will break on whitespace however. You'll need to output this yourself most likely, or use JS.

Comment: How can we achieve this JS.. Kindly help...

Comment: Also question why you want this in the first place. Having a long url in a table isn't very useful unless you plan on copying it out. Otherwise, you'd have it as a link.

Answer (score 3):

I can't think of a CSS-only solution. But using JavaScript you could add the word break opportunity tag `<wbr>`. This tells the browser - except for Internet Explorer - where it can insert breaks:

**JavaScript (using jQuery)**

```
$('#element').html( $('#element').html().replace(/\//g, '/<wbr>') );
```

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/EkfUR/

**As of your edit**

You edited your question while I was writing the fiddle. You can of course use another character than `/` used in the expression to be replaced with the `<wbr>`-tag.

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing in .css to break text part on specific point ( break row after letter 't' for example.

Search for 'word-break'

[caniuse word-break](http://caniuse.com/#search=word-break)

```
p {
    -ms-word-break: break-all;
    word-break: break-all;

     // Non standard for webkit
     word-break: break-word;

     -webkit-hyphens: auto;
     -moz-hyphens: auto;
     hyphens: auto;
 }
```

There is a nice topic relevant to your situation : [how-to-prevent-long-words-from-breaking-my-div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320184/how-to-prevent-long-words-from-breaking-my-div) invoking possibility to split long words by inserting soft hyphen (­) with a regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

You can try doing it on javascript.

1) Split the string in "**/**";

2) Append substrings from start to end, while the resulting line is smaller than the width of the `TD`;

3) If it's bigger, don't append the last piece, and place it in the next line (as in, put a `<br />` before it);

4) Do this until your split array is empty, which means you have your string broken in lines like you want.

Answer (score 0):

ok, maybe this is the worst approach you'll see, but it does the trick...
split the string into `span` and then use an `:after` whith a white space like this:

```
span:after{
 content:' ';
    font-size:0;
}
```

example here: http://jsfiddle.net/pavloschris/b7qeD/