# CSS break-word using symbols first

Tags: html, string, css, word-wrap

I don't find the `word-wrap: break-word;` rule too pleasant in the eyes in certain situations because it tends to break long strings in the wrong places given the right condition.

It produces something like this:

```
|--- DIV ---|
|           |
| English/S |
| panish    |
|           |
|-----------|
```

instead of

```
|--- DIV ---|
|           |
| English/  |
| Spanish   |
|           |
|-----------|
```

Is there a way for me to fine-tune my CSS rules so that it tries to break words through symbols first before breaking the actual words? If so, how do I do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the only way to achieve such behavior is by using `<wbr>`([mdn link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/wbr)) in your markup at the position you wish to cause the word break.

Have a look:

```css
.word-box{
  width:100px;
  margin:5em;
  border:1px solid #606266;
}
```

```html
<div id='break-wbr' class='word-box'>
English/<wbr>Spanish
</div>
```

It's also well [supported](http://caniuse.com/#search=wbr).

Another way to break at a position would be by using shy hyphens ( `&shy;`)

```css
.word-box{
  width:100px;
  margin:5em;
  border:1px solid #606266;
}
```

```html
<div id='break-shy' class='word-box' lang='en'>
English/&shy;Spanish
</div>
```

but the downside of using shy hyphens is that it inserts a visible hyphen at the point of word break.

*You can also have a look at a very similar and more detailed answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21780096/6517778).*

Comment: I really like the `<wbr>` approach but in my case all the text are dynamic and are coming from the database. `<wbr>` needs me to know off-hand where to put it. I guess what I could do is just append `<wbr>` to all symbols.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this.
word-break: keep-all;

Comment: maybe because English/Spanish is considered one word. Try English/ Spanish. with space after /.

Comment: I don't think that's an option for me.